# Gauss-Jordan for a system of four equations

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations

Given the system in $Z_5$

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x+3y+4z=0 \\ 
3x+2y+4z=0 \\ 
x+z=0 \\
3x+y=2
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Using Gauss-Jordan ($5R_2, R_2<->R_4, 5R_3, 5R_2$) I get to this point:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 3 & 4 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{matrix}
$$

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

i have got this here
$$x+3y+4z=0$$
multiplying the first equation by $-3$ and adding to the second we get:
$$-7y-8z=0$$
multiplying the first equation by $-1$ and adding to the third we get:
$$-3y-3z=0$$
and multiplying the first equation by $-3$ and adding to the fourth we get
$$-8y-12z=2$$
in $\mathbb{Z_5}$ we get
$$x+3y+4z=0$$
$$-2y-3z=0$$
$$-3y-3z=0$$
$$-3y-2z=2$$
the new System
$$x+3y+4z=0$$
$$2y+3z=0$$
$$3y+3z=0$$
$$3y+2z=3$$

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: i did the Gauss-algorythm

Comment: But you used no matrices

Comment: yes this is right, you can use Matrices and compare the results

Comment: I still don't understand what did you do.

Comment: Please edit the answer with other passages so I can understand better

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: Do you realize that you are in $Z_5$ and there's no $7,8,12$ etc?

Comment: yes i have it realized, should i write the equation System again?

Comment: Yes, so I can understand better.

Comment: that is fine,are you a Student?

Comment: Yes, I'm a student

Comment: Your system is still incorrect, there's no negative numbers in $Z_5$

Comment: ok you can multiply by $-1$

Comment: Are you serious? You clearly don't know what $Z_5$ mean.

Comment: i know what $\mathbb{Z_5}$ is, all numbers mod 5 one can also use negative numbers

Comment: The solution is $x=0$, $y=0$ and $z=3$ ?

Comment: The system has no solutions?

Comment: one Moment i will check it

Comment: yes this System has no solutions

Answer (score 0):

It will be simpler to take as set of representatives $\;\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2 \}$.

Let's proceed with row reduction of augmented matrix:

\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&-1&{}\mid 0\\-2&2&-1&{}\mid 0\\
1&0&1&{}\mid 0\\-2&1&0&{}\mid 2
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&-1&{}\mid 0\\0&-2&2&{}\mid 0\\
0&2&2&{}\mid 0\\0&2&-2&{}\mid 2
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2&-1&{}\mid 0\\0&-2&2&{}\mid 0\\
0&0&-1&{}\mid 0\\0&0&0&{}\mid 2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

So the system is inconsistent and there's no solution.